# integration using trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus

$$\int x^3 (16 - x^2)^{5/2} \mathrm dx$$

using: ($a^2 - x^2$)

x = 4 sin$\theta$

dx = 4cos$\theta$ d$\theta$

I attempted to solve this but am not getting very far.

Comment: Is it $\frac{(16-x^2)^5}{2}$ or $(16-x^2)^{5/2}$  ?

Comment: the second one. I couldn't figure out how to raise the fraction. thanks

Comment: Forgetting constants, you are integrating $$\cos^6\theta\sin^3\theta d\theta=\cos^6\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)\sin\theta d\theta$$. Let $u=\cos\theta$ to obtain $-u^6(1-u^2)du$

Comment: ok I have gotten this far, but cannot figure out what the next steps would be.